# Script to Create Colour Chip Layers in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions

I would like to automate the process of adding colour chip layers to my images. The images will only ever contain between 2–16 colours, and are pixel-perfect. I would like to be able to automatically scan the flat layer containing the image, and create rectangle layers for each colour in the image resulting in something like the below:
[image: Colour chips on example image]

I thought it could be possible using index colour to create a swatch palette, but not sure how I could then create the rectangles automatically using the colours in the saved palette?. Alternatively, can a script just scan the layer for every variant of colour since I can be sure there will only ever be max 16?

Is this possible? Or wishful thinking?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible one way or the other. I found two questions on Adobe Support Community about the Indexed Color approach: [1](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/how-can-i-get-scripting-access-to-color-values-in-the-indexed-color-table/td-p/5524581) and [2](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/how-do-i-export-the-color-table-act-file-using-a-script/td-p/11081410). But I'm thinking there is a more straightforward way to do it. Too late for me to look into right now. Probably someone will beat me to it. 

Comment: Thanks Wolff! Glad to read you think it's possible—that's super promising. Those Adobe answers are definitely helpful thanks, I'll continue my research!

Comment: For automating the creation of the rectangles, here's a possible solution: you could make a .psd template with 16 layers, each with a stroke and fill, each set to invisible.  Your script would open the file and make the appropriate number visible, change the fill, group the contents, and drop it into your main document.This also allows you to easily change the style and layout of the swatches later if you wish.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, that's super helpful and exactly what I'll do. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script that automatically adds a color chip for each color in an image. It makes use of indexed color's ability to create a color table and uses those colors to draw the chips.

The script is a bit raw and doesn't check for every possible thing that could go wrong. Let me know if something doesn't work as intended.

I haven't commented every line in the script, but I've divided it into some sections that I will go through here.

## Walkthrough

#### Set options

First we define some options you can customize to make the script fit your needs.

- **size:** The width and height of a chip in pixels.
- **spacing:** The distance between chips in pixels.
- **padding:** The inner padding of the box behind the chips.
- **offset:** The horizontal and vertical distance from the upper left corner in pixels.
- **backgroundColor:** The RGB color of the box behind the chips.
- **layerName:** The name of the layer containing the chips.

#### Save history state

Here we save the state of the document so we can later revert to it just before adding the chip layer.

#### Change color mode to RGB color

In case the document already is in indexed color, we change the color mode to RGB. Sometimes a color table contains duplicates of colors and we need to get rid of those.

#### Change color mode to indexed color

Now we can change the color mode to indexed color. The settings make sure that we will use an exact palette, don't force colors and have no transparency.

#### Create array for chip colors

We create an array to hold the list of chip colors.

#### Get chip colors from color table

This part is a bit messy. Unfortunately it seems that there is no easy way to directly access the colors in a color table. So in this workaround we first save a temporary PSD file and then examine the raw binary data to extract the individual colors of the color table and add them to the array of chip colors. (This code is based on on the answer from r-bin to [a question on the Adobe Support Community](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/how-do-i-export-the-color-table-act-file-using-a-script/td-p/11081410).)

#### Revert to saved history state

Since changing to index color mode have flattened the document, we revert to the state we saved earlier to preserve the original layers.

#### Change color mode to RGB color

In case the original document was in indexed color, we need to change the color mode to RGB. This is necessary because we want to make sure the color chips get their own separate layer and because the chosen background color might not be present in the color table.

#### Add chips layer

We add a new layer for the color chips and change its name to the one specified in the options.

#### Draw chips background

Here we draw the background box for the color chips using the dimensions given in the options. It's done by defining a selection and then filling it with a color.

#### Draw chips

For each chip color we draw a box at the proper position using the dimensions given in the options.

#### Deselect

To wrap it up neatly, we deselect so the last selection doesn't linger on.

## Script

```
// Set options
var options = {
    size: 16,
    spacing: 2,
    padding: 4,
    offset: [4, 4],
    backgroundColor: [255, 255, 255],
    layerName: "Color Chips"
};

// Save history state
var savedState = app.activeDocument.activeHistoryState;

// Change color mode to RGB color
app.activeDocument.changeMode(ChangeMode.RGB);

// Change color mode to indexed color
var indexedConversionOptions = new IndexedConversionOptions();
indexedConversionOptions.palette = Palette.EXACT;
indexedConversionOptions.forced = ForcedColors.NONE;
indexedConversionOptions.transparency = false;
app.activeDocument.changeMode(ChangeMode.INDEXEDCOLOR, indexedConversionOptions);

// Create array for chip colors
var chipColors = [];

// Get chip colors from color table
// (Based on the answer from r-bin at https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/how-do-i-export-the-color-table-act-file-using-a-script/td-p/11081410)
var tempFile = new File(Folder.temp.fsName + "/" + "~tmp.psd");
var d = new ActionDescriptor();
var d1 = new ActionDescriptor();
d1.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("maximizeCompatibility"), false);
d.putObject(stringIDToTypeID("as"), stringIDToTypeID("photoshop35Format"), d1);
d.putPath(stringIDToTypeID("in"), tempFile);
d.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("copy"), true);
d.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("spot"), false);
d.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("alphaChannels"), false);
d.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("layers"), false);
d.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("embedProfiles"), false);
d.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("annotType"), false);
executeAction(stringIDToTypeID("save"), d, DialogModes.NO);
var s = "";
tempFile.open("r");
tempFile.encoding = "BINARY";
tempFile.seek(25, 0);
tempFile.read(1);
s = tempFile.read(4);
var len = s.charCodeAt(0)<<24 | s.charCodeAt(1)<<16 | s.charCodeAt(2)<<8 | s.charCodeAt(3);
var table = tempFile.read(len);
s = tempFile.read(4);
len = s.charCodeAt(0)<<24 | s.charCodeAt(1)<<16 | s.charCodeAt(2)<<8 | s.charCodeAt(3);
var data = tempFile.read(len);
tempFile.close();
tempFile.remove();
var colorCount = 255;
var n = data.indexOf("8BIM"+ String.fromCharCode(0x04,0x16,0,0,0,0,0,2));
if (n >= 0) {
    colorCount = data.charCodeAt(n+12)<<8 | data.charCodeAt(n+13);
}
for (var i = 0; i < colorCount; i++) {
    chipColors.push([table.charCodeAt(i), table.charCodeAt(256+i), table.charCodeAt(512+i)]);
}

// Revert to saved history state
app.activeDocument.activeHistoryState = savedState; 

// Change color mode to RGB color
app.activeDocument.changeMode(ChangeMode.RGB);

// Add chips layer
var chipsLayer = app.activeDocument.artLayers.add();
chipsLayer.name = options.layerName;

// Draw chips background
var x1 = options.offset[0];
var y1 = options.offset[1];
var x2 = x1 + 2 * options.padding + chipColors.length * options.size + (chipColors.length - 1) * options.spacing;
var y2 = y1 + 2 * options.padding + options.size;
app.activeDocument.selection.select([[x1, y1], [x1, y2], [x2, y2], [x2, y1]]);
var chipsBackgroundColor = new SolidColor();
chipsBackgroundColor.rgb.red = options.backgroundColor[0];
chipsBackgroundColor.rgb.green = options.backgroundColor[1];
chipsBackgroundColor.rgb.blue = options.backgroundColor[2];
app.activeDocument.selection.fill(chipsBackgroundColor);

// Draw chips
for (var i = 0; i < chipColors.length; i++) {
    var x1 = options.offset[0] + options.padding + i * (options.size + options.spacing);
    var y1 = options.offset[1] + options.padding;
    var x2 = x1 + options.size;
    var y2 = y1 + options.size;
    app.activeDocument.selection.select([[x1, y1], [x1, y2], [x2, y2], [x2, y1]]);
    var chipColor = new SolidColor();
    chipColor.rgb.red = chipColors[i][0];
    chipColor.rgb.green = chipColors[i][1];
    chipColor.rgb.blue = chipColors[i][2];
    app.activeDocument.selection.fill(chipColor);
}

// Deselect
app.activeDocument.selection.deselect();
```

## Usage example

Here I've recorded an action running the script, so I can add the color chips with one click:

[image]

## Notes

- If the *size* given in the options is too big and/or there are too many colors, obviously there won't be room in the image for all the color chips.
- The colors will appear in the order Photoshop chooses when converting to indexed color. If you want to order according to hue, saturation  or lightness, you need to sort the array of chip colors before drawing.
- If you want a stroke around each color chip, it's possible to add to the script.